# Bash: how to use variable value as substring of a folder name

Tags: bash, shell, variables, substring

In a bash script, I don't remember how to use the value of a variable as a substring of a folder name. Example:

I have folders:

```
test_1.0_xxx  test_1.2_yyy test_1.4_zzz
```

And I want to do the following:

```
for i in 1.0 1.2 1.4
do
  cd test_$i_*
  # do something
done
```

The syntax seems to be wrong:

```
bash: cd: test_*: No such file or directory
```

I also tried using backticks around `$i`, but with no success. How should I do it?

Comment: Added the error to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "1.0" "1.2" "1.4"
do
  cd test_${i}_*
  # do something
done
```

Comment: Thanks! How does this differ from the solution suggested by Will Vousden?

Comment: Enclosing the variable between brackets is the right way to avoid naming issue. Furthermore, is always better to enclose the for parameters with double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore following `$i` is being counted as part of the variable name. Try enclosing it in quotes:

```
for i in 1.0 1.2 1.4
do
  cd test_"$i"_*
  # do something
done
```

**Edit**: matteomattei's version is probably more correct.